# How can I perform transformations on vector-valued random variables?

Tags: data-transformation, random-variable

I'm trying to find a way to compute presence/absence probabilities over random vectors that contain sequences of values rather then presence/absence indicators. Suppose I have a set $S$ of possible values, vector length $L$, and random vector $\vec{W} \in S^{L}$ with known distribution $P(\vec{W})$. I can define a function to convert one of these vectors into a bit vector indicating whether any given value in $S$ was present or absent in $\vec{W}$:

$\sigma(\vec{W}) = \langle \bigvee_{j}^{L} W_{j}=s : \forall s \in S \rangle$

But since any function of a random variable is also a random variable, can I somehow derive a probability function for particular presence/absence vectors (call these $\vec{X}$) that is expressed in terms of the original $P(\vec{W})$?

### Question

In the example (below) I define a function for computing probabilities on the presence/absence vectors, but I basically "eyeballed" it and don't have much confidence in the approach. Is there a more systematic way of computing the distribution over such a function of a random vector? Does "change of variables" provide any guidance?

### Example

Setup:
$$
S = \{ 1, 2 \} \\
L = 2 \\
P(\vec{W}=\langle 1,1\rangle) = 0.1 \\
P(\vec{W}=\langle 1,2\rangle) = 0.1 \\
P(\vec{W}=\langle 2,1\rangle) = 0.4 \\
P(\vec{W}=\langle 2,2\rangle) = 0.4
$$

Compute presence/absence vectors:
$$
\sigma(\langle 1,1\rangle) = \langle 1,0\rangle \\
\sigma(\langle 1,2\rangle) = \langle 1,1\rangle \\
\sigma(\langle 2,1\rangle) = \langle 1,1\rangle \\
\sigma(\langle 2,2\rangle) = \langle 0,1\rangle
$$

Compute presence/absence vector probs:
$$
P(\vec{X}=\langle1,1\rangle) = \sum_{w' \in S^{L} \wedge \sigma(w')=\langle1,1\rangle} P(\vec{W}=w') = 0.1 + 0.4 = 0.5
$$

Or, generally,
$$
P(\vec{X}=x') = \sum_{w' \in S^{L} \wedge \sigma(w')=x'} P(\vec{W}=w')
$$

For a particular value:
$$
P(X_i=b) = \sum_{x' \in \{0,1\}^{|S|} \wedge x'_i=b} P(\vec{X}=x') \\
P(X_i=b) = \sum_{x' \in \{0,1\}^{|S|} \wedge x'_i=b} \sum_{w' \in S^{L} \wedge \sigma(w')=x'} P(\vec{W}=w')
$$

Comment: A similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240164/cdf-of-sum-of-dependent-random-variables . By treating my random vector as a vector of random variables whose joint distribution is known, the answer there may apply. But I'm still hoping to find a general statement of how that sort of solution was arrived at.